# Login page - Goes straight to members page and redirects to login page

Tags: php, authentication

I am having this minor problem with the login page. Clicking the login button goes straight to members page and redirects back to login page. Please take a look at my website: http://www.nigelsham.co.uk > click "login".

If you enter the login details:
username: 007
password: Password123!

It shows the users data in members page.

Here is the code:
Login page - http://pastebin.com/8XJepv7d

Members page PHP code:

```
<?php
session_start();

    if (!$_SESSION["myusername"]) {
        $ogmeta = '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://nigelsham.co.uk/login.php">';
        echo $ogmeta;
    } else{
        $user = $_SESSION['myusername'];
        $pass = $_SESSION['mypassword'];
        $email = $_SESSION['myemail'];
    }
    ?>
```

Any suggestions?
I have spent a lot of time fixing the SESSIONS, do you think SESSIONS could be part of the problem? Or could it be the $ogmeta variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the problem is the login button should be directly to login, right?
So, change the href in the login button to redirect to login.php

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can't believe I didn't see that properly.. Think I should take a break from coding. Been doing this everyday after work.

Comment: You are welcome, I get that can happen sometimes, good luck with the rest of it.